# Getting Available Certificate uploaded on azure storage

Tags: c#-4.0, azure, certificate, virtual-machine

I want to get all uploaded certificate on storage in azure to use these certificate associate with VM when I creating VM's using rest-api to.

Is it necessary, the certificate should available on local machine?
If yes, is there any way to install certificate locally, when the web site/ portal in open on any machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the certificate on each machine that uses REST api to be able to function.

The point of the private and public keys are to maintain security.  I dont think this would be something you would want to put on a website for anyone to be able to install.

That being said, if you are making the REST call via a website, then only the server hosting the application needs to have the certificate installed.

I build a webrequest that has the REST URL in it, [like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157189.aspx), then build the response.

```
private HttpWebResponse CallAzure(HttpWebRequest request, string postData)
        {
            var certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certs = certificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, CertificateThumbprint, false);

            if (request.Method.ToUpper() == "POST")
            {
                var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.LoadXml(postData);

                var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                xDoc.Save(streamWriter);

                streamWriter.Close();
                requestStream.Close();
            }
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(certs[0]);
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-03-01");

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            return (HttpWebResponse)response;
        }
```

I have found it easiest to [install the certificate via PowerShell.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554332.aspx#BKMK_Configure)

If you want to generate your own publishsettingfile [here is a very easy app to do it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/5054447c-b04a-4a69-bf89-d17c441b1c73/how-to-generate-publishsettings-file-from-existing-management-certificate).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.IO;

namespace CreatePublishSettingsFile
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string subscriptionId = "[your subscription id]";
        private static string subscriptionName = "My Awesome Subscription";
        private static string certificateThumbprint = "[certificate thumbprint. the certificate must have private key]";
        private static StoreLocation certificateStoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
        private static StoreName certificateStoreName = StoreName.My;
        private static string publishFileFormat = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<PublishData>
  <PublishProfile
    PublishMethod=""AzureServiceManagementAPI""
    Url=""https://management.core.windows.net/""
    ManagementCertificate=""{0}"">
    <Subscription
      Id=""{1}""
      Name=""{2}"" />
  </PublishProfile>
</PublishData>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(certificateStoreName, certificateStoreLocation);
            certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = certificateStore.Certificates;
            var matchingCertificates = certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certificateThumbprint, false);
            if (matchingCertificates.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No matching certificate found. Please ensure that proper values are specified for Certificate Store Name, Location and Thumbprint");
            }
            else
            {
                var certificate = matchingCertificates[0];
                certificateData = Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, string.Empty));
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subscriptionName))
                {
                    subscriptionName = subscriptionId;
                }
                string publishSettingsFileData = string.Format(publishFileFormat, certificateData, subscriptionId, subscriptionName);
                string fileName = Path.GetTempPath() + subscriptionId + ".publishsettings";
                File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publishSettingsFileData));
                Console.WriteLine("Publish settings file written successfully at: " + fileName);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate the program.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```